# Express-getting this error message trying to run server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to run the server on the back-end of a project I'm doing and I keep getting this error message and it stops the server from running. I installed express generator if that makes any difference

```
> server@0.0.0 start /Users/username/Desktop/project/server
> node ./bin/www

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'http-errors'
Require stack:
- /Users/username/Desktop/project/server/main/app.js
- /Users/username/Desktop/project/server/bin/www
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/Desktop/project/server/main/app.js:1:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:791:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/username/Desktop/project/server/main/app.js',
    '/Users/username/Desktop/project/server/bin/www'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! server@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the server@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/.npm/_logs/2020-11-13T03_27_43_635Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It clearly says `Error: Cannot find module 'http-errors'`, so you probably don't have the package installed locally. Run `npm i http-errors` to download it.

Alternatively, if you'd like to save the package as a dependency in your project, run `npm i http-errors --save`